# creating a custom keyboard shortcut using javascript

Tags: javascript

I work in a tour company where we make bookings and the system they are using requires lots of typing and clicking. To make my work easier I have installed a Google Chrome Extension where you can run a javascript code via keyboard shortcut. I was able to make it work on most of the buttons by using `getElementsByClassName` and `getElementById` but there is this certain button where I can't make it work.

the button code is

```
A href class="button" name="cmdJn" onclick="fnOptionsClear(); return false;
```

What should be the code? In other buttons I use `document.getElementsByClass('bob')[0].click()` and it works

I'm just new to javascript. thanks

Comment: @basic Elements can have multiple click event handlers.  Removing the existing inline handler is not necessary.

Comment: Please show us the code you're trying to use with this element.  It does not have a `bob` class.

Comment: If you don't know for sure, don't say it @basic. You can add many event handlers of the same type to one element, i.e two "click" events.

Comment: Also, we don't know what the plugin does. However you could always select it on the attribute name. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute

Answer (score 0):

Is your issue that the element doesn't have an id or unique class on it? If so you can do something like `document.querySelector('[name="cmdJn"]')`.

document.querySelector allows you to use css selectors to find elements. You can find out more about css selectors [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the `document.getElementsByClass('bob')` code you are attempting to select something that has the class of "bob". Your element has the class of button. Change the class element into bob, or run the code `document.getElementsByClass('button')`